# Change text color in EditorRow

Tags: c#, colors, devexpress

I can change color for all records in VGridControl.

`vGridControl1.Appearance.ReadOnlyRecordValue.ForeColor`

But I don't know how to change color only for one row.

```
EditorRow row = new EditorRow(id);
row.Name = "row" + id;
row.Properties.Row.Appearance.ForeColor = ColorText;
row.Properties.Row.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;
```

I try do something. But it is does not work.
Help me, please.

Well, if I use event CustomDrawRowHeaderCell, I can change header's color. Code:

```
private void vGridControl1_CustomDrawRowHeaderCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Events.CustomDrawRowHeaderCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            System.Drawing.Color ColorText = Color.FromArgb(m_Color.r, m_Color.g, m_Color.b);
            e.Row.Appearance.ForeColor = ColorText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

But, when I try to change text row color, I have the problem: I can't change text row color. But I can change row BackColor. Can anyone help me?
Code:

```
        private void vGridControl1_CustomDrawRowValueCell(object sender, DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Events.CustomDrawRowValueCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Color ColorText = Color.FromArgb(m_Color.r, m_Color.g, m_Color.b);
            e.Row.Appearance.ForeColor = ColorText;
            e.Row.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;
            e.Row.Appearance.BackColor = ColorText;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

Comment: You might have better chance getting an answer at the DevExpress Q&A  Support Site: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would propose that you go and check out [DevExpress](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument1236) documentaion on the gridview.

if you need a row to change color you can do it like this:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      gridControl1.DataSource = new List<Structure>
        {
          new Structure {Id = 1, Val1 = "nr 1"}, 
          new Structure {Id = 2, Val1 = "nr 2"}, 
          new Structure {Id = 3, Val1 = "nr 3"}
        };
    }

    private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
       int myExpectedRowHandle = 1;
       if (e.RowHandle == myExpectedRowHandle)
       {
         e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
       }
    }
  }

  public class Structure
  {
    public string Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
```

You handle the `RowStyle` Event for this paticular job.
The result will loke like this:
[image]

**EDIT**

To set the color of just one cell - handle the event `RowCellStyle`

In my examle you would look like this:

```
private void gridView1_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
  int myExpectedRowHandle = 1;
  if (e.Column != colVal1 || e.RowHandle != myExpectedRowHandle)
    return;

  e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Crimson;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you change row BackColor. I do it in event vGridControl1_CustomDrawRowHeaderCell. Can you tell me how to change text color in the cell(is it possible in the row?).
In this example I need to change color for text nr 2. Not background color.

Comment: The question was about vertical grid VGridControl. The answer is right for XtraGridControl.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I insert Row in VGridControl.
Can I change text color in this function?

```
enter code here


 private void InsertNewRow(string id, string text, int type)
    {
        EditorRow row = new EditorRow(id);
        row.Name = "row" + id;
        row.Properties.ImageIndex = type;
        //vGridControl1.Appearance.ReadOnlyRecordValue.ForeColor = ColorText;
        M_Objects myColorObject = new M_Objects();
        if (GetObjectById(id, ref myColorObject) >= 0)
        {
            m_Color = myColorObject.Color;
        }
        System.Drawing.Color ColorText = Color.FromArgb(m_Color.r, m_Color.g, m_Color.b);
        row.Appearance.ForeColor = ColorText;//here I try to change color
        row.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;//It does not work

        if (vGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Count == 0)
            vGridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add("TextEdit");
        row.Properties.RowEdit = vGridControl1.RepositoryItems[0];
        row.Properties.Value = text;


        row.Height = 28;
        row.Properties.ReadOnly = true;
        vGridControl1.Rows["MainRow"].ChildRows.Add(row);//I don't write this code. Is it right?
    }
```